# ARIMA forecasting with xts object

Tags: r, forecasting, xts, arima

I have two xts objects (one train and one test/validation set) and I would like to use ARIMA models based on the train data set to carry out one-step-ahead forecast on the test dataset (namely, one-step out of sample forecasting). However, whenever I use the "forecast" function, the results seem weird. It's probably because forecast() assumes a time series object and I have xts objects.
I was wondering if anyone knows an R command for what I want to accomplish? I would also like to produce a graph like the uploaded one, but once again it turns out very weird due to using xts objects I believe.
I would really appreciate your help as I'm really stuck on this step of my analysis!:)
My training set:

> dput(head(xts.data))
> structure(c(2.74983173511717, 2.75110969056266, 2.79971738962803,
> 2.81540871942271, 2.93438864331294, 3.01504458458636, NA, 0.00127795544549159,
> 0.0486076990653772, 0.0156913297946755, 0.11897992389023, 0.0806559412734247
> ), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1333324800, 1333411200,
> 1333497600, 1333584000, 1333929600, 1334016000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L,
> 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("lVIXCLS", "ldVIXCLS")))

My validation set:

> dput(head(validation))
> structure(c(3.2846635654062, 3.31890213893533, 3.33077491736561,
> 3.38371206732114, 3.33434507467431, 3.27184770963431), class = c("xts",
> "zoo"), index = structure(c(1601510400, 1601596800, 1601856000,
> 1601942400, 1602028800, 1602115200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L,
> 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "lVIXCLS"))

[This is my training set (modelling lVIXCLS with ARIMA)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpQOz.png)

[This is my validation dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqY8O.png)
[Graph I would like to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an3we.png)

R-code:

```
    data<- read_excel("VIXCLS 10 year data.xls")
    data<-na.omit(data)
    date <- as.Date(data$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
    ts.data<-data
    ts.data$Date<-as.Date(ts.data$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
    xts.data2 <- xts(ts.data[2],ts.data$Date)
    ts.data$Date<-as.Date(ts.data$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
    xts.data2 <- xts(ts.data[2],ts.data$Date)
    xts.data<-xts.data2$lVIXCLS[0:2139]
    validation<-xts.data2$lVIXCLS[2140:2517]
```

Comment: Could you please share some small parts of your data and your code that you used to analyze your data? It's just too difficult for other users to analyze images to reproduce the trouble you are facing.  One way of sharing your data is by using `dput`. For example: `dput(head(xts.data))`

Comment: Hello! Thank you, I just added some more info with the command you suggested! :)

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. I mean, please copy and paste the result of `dput(head(xts.data))` to this page as code texts, and as a part of your question, not as another image. Thanks

Comment: Please also share the R code that you used to analyze `xts.data` so that other users can run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to apply the functions in {forecast} package to your data, you just need to convert the data to a time series by using `as.ts`. For example:

```
# Your data

train.dat <- structure(c(2.74983173511717, 2.75110969056266, 2.79971738962803, 
             2.81540871942271, 2.93438864331294, 3.01504458458636, NA, 
             0.00127795544549159, 0.0486076990653772, 0.0156913297946755, 
             0.11897992389023, 0.0806559412734247 ), 
             class = c("xts", "zoo"), 
             index = structure(c(1333324800, 1333411200, 1333497600, 1333584000, 
                     1333929600, 1334016000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), 
             .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("lVIXCLS", "ldVIXCLS")))

library(forecast)

fit <- auto.arima(as.ts(train.dat[,1]))
fit
# Series: as.ts(train.dat[, 1]) 
# ARIMA(0,1,0) 
# 
# sigma^2 = 0.004656:  log likelihood = 6.33
# AIC=-10.66   AICc=-9.33   BIC=-11.05
```

Then, you can use the model to forecast values:

```
forecast(fit)
# Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
# 7       3.015045 2.927599 3.102491 2.881307 3.148782
# 8       3.015045 2.891377 3.138712 2.825912 3.204177
# 9       3.015045 2.863584 3.166506 2.783405 3.246684
# 10       3.015045 2.840153 3.189937 2.747570 3.282519
# 11       3.015045 2.819509 3.210580 2.715999 3.314090
# 12       3.015045 2.800846 3.229243 2.687457 3.342632
# 13       3.015045 2.783684 3.246405 2.661209 3.368880
# 14       3.015045 2.767710 3.262379 2.636779 3.393310
# 15       3.015045 2.752707 3.277383 2.613833 3.416256
# 16       3.015045 2.738516 3.291573 2.592131 3.437959
```

You can also plot the forecast data using `plot`:

```
plot(fit)
```

[image]

You can analyze the test data with the same steps as above.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate this:))